# Get selected object from the tree based on passing argument

Tags: java, oop, collections, java-8, depth-first-search

So I have this Person object. Each person have list of person object and so on..

```
public class Person {
    ....
    private List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();

    ....

    public List<Person> getPeople() {
        return people;
    }

    public void setPeople(List<Person> people) {
        this.people = people;
    }
```

[image]

I already the max dept answer using the following code, answer is whatever int I get minus 1

```
public static int maxDepth(Person p) {
        int maxChildrenDepth = 0;
        for (Person c: p.getPeople()) {
            maxChildrenDepth = Math.max(maxChildrenDepth, maxDepth(c));
        }
        return 1 + maxChildrenDepth;
    }
```

so if i pass Person object & int into method, let say getPersonLevel(List allPerson, 1) , I should get all the Person object inside the List which are blue box, if I enter 2, i should get all the object inside the list from the red color box and so on depending on the int argument.. how do i get to that? Any help in appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one works !

```
public Set<Person> getPersonLevel(Person person, int depth) {
       Set<Person> aList = new HashSet<>();

       if (depth == 1)
           aList.addAll(person.getPeople());

       if (depth > 1){
           for (Person pp : person.getPeople()) {
                   aList.addAll(getPersonLevel(pp, depth -1));
           }
       }
       return aList;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than passing the person as parameter of the method, why not make `maxDepth` and `getPersonLevel` methods of the class Person ?

As a result you would have :

```
public class Person {

    private Set<Person> people = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<Person> getPeople() {
        return people;
    }

    public void setPeople(Set<Person> people) {
        this.people = people;
    }

    public int maxDepth() {
        int maxChildrenDepth = 0;
        for (Person prs : people) {
            maxChildrenDepth = Math.max(maxChildrenDepth, prs.maxDepth());
        }
        return 1 + maxChildrenDepth;
  }

  public Set<Person> getPersonLevel(int depth) {
      Set<Person> ppl = new HashSet<>();
      ppl.addAll(gatherEmployees(ppl, depth));
      return ppl;
  }

  private Set<Person> gatherEmployees(Set<Person> ppl, int depth) {
      if (depth - 1 > 0 && people != null) {
          people.forEach(prs -> ppl.addAll(prs.gatherEmployees(ppl, depth - 1)));
      }
      return people;
  }
}
```

Comment: it does not work -->  
getPersonLevel does not work as it returns empty

Comment: Sorry, I wrote that on the fly, I didn't take the time to test the code. I edited my answer, this version has been tested and I can assure you it works !